# Find the laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Find the Laurent expansion of $\dfrac{e^\frac{1}{z}}{z+1}$ in the
> domain $|z|>0$.

My attempt:
Since we have to work on domain $|z|>0$, let $z=\dfrac{1}{t}$, so I have to find the Laurent expansion of $\dfrac{te^t}{t+1}$ at $t=0$. Particularly, I have to find the Laurent expansion of $\dfrac{e^t}{t+1}$ at $t=0$.
I already knew that $$e^t=\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^n}{n!},\quad\forall t\in\mathbb{C}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{t+1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nt^n,\quad\forall |t|<1.$$
But I don't know how to find the product of these two series. Could someone help me pr have another way to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has a pole at $z=-1$, so your domain is either $0<|z|<1$ or $|z|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

The product of those two series – and they are really *Taylor* rather than Laurent swifties in $t$ – is the convolution:
$$\frac{e^t}{1+t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k!}$$
Thus the Laurent series of the original function is
$$\frac{e^{1/z}}{1+z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1/z)^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k!}$$